# Javascript codes not working in fluid layouts + Adobe CS6 Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have started learning responsive web sites. As a part of it I started using Fluid Grid Layout with Dreamviewer CS 6. But the problem is that java script functions are not working for toggles.

```
[------------------------------Nav Bar(nav)--------------------------------------------------------------------] [profile]
```

As shown in the figure profile div has a drop down menu and for the nav bar when the screen width is below 480, horizontal nav bar will convert will change to vertical bar and has a toggle to show submenu.

help me out

```js
//right click disable
$(function() {
    $(this).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}); 

//drop down -logout
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(".account").click(function() {
        var X=$(this).attr('id');
        if(X==1) {
            $(".submenu").hide();
            $(this).attr('id', '0'); 
        } else {
            $(".submenu").show();
            $(this).attr('id', '1');
        }
    });
    
    //Mouse click on sub menu
    $(".submenu").mouseup(function() {
        return false;
    });
    
    //Mouse click on my account link
    $(".account").mouseup(function(){
        return false;
    });
    
    //Document Click
    $(document).mouseup(function(){
        $(".submenu").hide();
        $(".account").attr('id', '');
    });
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* Simple fluid media
Note: Fluid media requires that you remove the media's height and width attributes from the HTML
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluid-images/ 
*/
img, object, embed, video {
    max-width: 100%;
}

/* IE 6 does not support max-width so default to width 100% */
.ie6 img {
    width:100%;
}

/*
Dreamweaver Fluid Grid Properties
----------------------------------
dw-num-cols-mobile:     5;
dw-num-cols-tablet:     8;
dw-num-cols-desktop:    12;
dw-gutter-percentage:   25;
Inspiration from "Responsive Web Design" by Ethan Marcotte 
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design
and Golden Grid System by Joni Korpi
http://goldengridsystem.com/
*/
/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .gridContainer {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 87.36%;
        padding-left: 1.82%;
        padding-right: 1.82%;
    }

    #nav {
        clear: none;
        float: left;
        text-align : center;
        margin-left: 4.1666%;
        width: 58.3333%;
        display: block;
    }

    #nav > ul {
        border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
        border-radius: 5px;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        max-width: 200px;
    }

    #nav > ul > li a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px;
        color: #666;
    }

    #nav > ul > li > a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    }

    #nav > ul > li > a:hover {
        color: #000;
        background: #e5e5e5;
    }

    #nav > ul > li > a.active {
        background: #e5e5e5;
    }

    #nav > ul > li ul {
        display: none;
        padding: 10px 20px 10px 30px;
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    }

    #nav > ul > li ul li {
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

    #nav > ul > li ul li a {
        border: 0;
        padding: 5px 10px 5px 0;
    }

    #nav > ul > li ul li a:hover {
        color: #000;
    }

    #nav > ul > li.dropdown {
        position: relative;
    }

    #nav > ul > li.dropdown:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
        top: 14px;
        border-top: 5px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
        border-left: 5px solid #686868;
    }

    #nav > ul > li.dropdown.open:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        right: 12px;
        top: 17px;
        border-left: 5px solid transparent;
        border-right: 5px solid transparent;
        border-top: 5px solid #686868;
    }

    #profile {
        clear: none;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 20.1666%;
        width: 16.6666%;
        display: block;
        color: #555;    
        text-align:left;
    }

    .submenu {
        background: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        top: -12px;
        left: -20px;
        z-index: 100;
        width: 135px;
        display: none;
        margin-left: 10px;
        padding: 40px 0 5px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
        clear:both;
    }

    #profile li a {
        color: #555555;
        display: block;
        font-family: arial;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 6px 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    #profile li a:hover {
        background:#155FB0;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    a.account {
        font-size: 11px;
        line-height: 16px;
        color: #555;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 110;
        display: block;
        padding: 11px 0 0 20px;
        height: 28px;
        width: 121px;
        margin: -11px 0 0 -10px;
        text-decoration: none;   
        cursor:pointer;
    }

    .root {
        list-style:none;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        font-size: 11px;
        padding: 11px 0 0 0px;
        border-top:1px solid #dedede;
    }

}

/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
    .gridContainer {
        width: 90.675%;
        padding-left: 1.1625%;
        padding-right: 1.1625%;
    }

    #nav {
        clear: none;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 2.5641%;
        width: 74.3589%;
        display: block;
        text-align : center;
    }

    #nav ul ul {
        display : none;
    }

    #nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display : block;
    }

    #nav ul {
        background-color : #fff;
        margin-top : 10px;
        padding : 0 20px;
        list-style : none;
        position : relative;
        display: inline-block;
        zoom: 1;
        *display: inline;
        margin-right : -80px;
        font-family :'Lato', sans-serif;
        text-transform : uppercase;
        font-size : 1em;
    }

    #nav ul li {
        float : left;
    }

    #nav ul li:hover {
        border-bottom : 5px solid #339966;
        color : #fff;
    }

    #nav ul li a:hover {
        color : #ffffff;
        background : #1bbc9b;
    }

    #nav ul li a {
        display : block;
        padding : 0.3em 0.8em;
        font-family :'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-size : 0.9em;
        color : #444;
        text-decoration : none;
    }

    #nav ul ul {
        background-color : #fff;
        border-radius : 0;
        padding : 0;
        position : absolute;
        top : 100%;
        box-shadow : 0 0 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        z-index: 999999
    }

    #nav ul ul li {
        float : none;
        position : relative;
        font-family :'Lato', sans-serif;
        text-transform : uppercase;
        font-size : 0.85em;
    }

    #nav ul ul li a {
        padding : 0.4em 1.2em;
        color : #000;
        font-family :'Lato', sans-serif;
        text-transform : uppercase;
        font-size : 1em;
    }

    #nav ul ul:before {
        content :"";
        display : block;
        height : 20px;
        position : absolute;
        top : -20px;
        width : 100%;
    }

    #profile {
        clear: none;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 12.5641%;
        width: 10.2564%;
        display: block;
        color: #555;    
        text-align:left;
    }

    .submenu {
        background: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        top: -12px;
        left: -20px;
        z-index: 100;
        width: 135px;
        display: none;
        margin-left: 10px;
        padding: 40px 0 5px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
        clear:both;
    }

    #profile li a {
        color: #555555;
        display: block;
        font-family: arial;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 6px 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    #profile li a:hover {
        background:#155FB0;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    a.account {
        font-size: 11px;
        line-height: 16px;
        color: #555;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 110;
        display: block;
        padding: 11px 0 0 20px;
        height: 28px;
        width: 121px;
        margin: -11px 0 0 -10px;
        text-decoration: none;   
        cursor:pointer;
    }

    .root {
        list-style:none;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        font-size: 11px;
        padding: 11px 0 0 0px;
        border-top:1px solid #dedede;
    }

}

/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    .gridContainer {
        width: 88.5%;
        max-width: 1232px;
        padding-left: 0.75%;
        padding-right: 0.75%;
        margin: auto;
    }

    #nav {
        clear: none;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 1.6949%;
        width: 83.0508%;
        display: block;
        text-align : center;
    }

    #nav ul ul {
        display : none;
    }

    #nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display : block;
    }

    #nav ul {
        background-color : #fff;
        margin-top : 10px;
        padding : 0 20px;
        list-style : none;
        position : relative;
        display: inline-block;
        zoom: 1;
        *display: inline;
        margin-right : -80px;
        font-family :'Lato', sans-serif;
        text-transform : uppercase;
        font-size : 1em;
    }

    #nav ul li {
        float : left;
    }

    #nav ul li:hover {
        border-bottom : 5px solid #339966;
        color : #fff;
    }

    #nav ul li a:hover {
        color : #ffffff;
        background : #1bbc9b;
    }

    #nav ul li a {
        display : block;
        padding : 0.3em 0.8em;
        font-family :'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-size : 0.9em;
        color : #444;
        text-decoration : none;
    }

    #nav ul ul {
        background-color : #fff;
        border-radius : 0;
        padding : 0;
        position : absolute;
        top : 100%;
        box-shadow : 0 0 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        z-index: 999999
    }

    #nav ul ul li {
        float : none;
        position : relative;
        font-family :'Lato', sans-serif;
        text-transform : uppercase;
        font-size : 0.85em;
    }

    #nav ul ul li a {
        padding : 0.4em 1.2em;
        color : #000;
        font-family :'Lato', sans-serif;
        text-transform : uppercase;
        font-size : 1em;
    }

    #nav ul ul:before {
        content :"";
        display : block;
        height : 20px;
        position : absolute;
        top : -20px;
        width : 100%;
    }

    #profile {
        clear: none;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 6.6949%;
        width: 6.7796%;
        display: block;
    }

    .submenu {
        background: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        top: -12px;
        left: -20px;
        z-index: 100;
        width: 135px;
        display: none;
        margin-left: 10px;
        padding: 40px 0 5px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
        clear:both;
    }

    #profile li a {
        color: #555555;
        display: block;
        font-family: arial;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 6px 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    #profile li a:hover {
        background:#155FB0;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    a.account {
        font-size: 11px;
        line-height: 16px;
        color: #555;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 110;
        display: block;
        padding: 11px 0 0 20px;
        height: 28px;
        width: 121px;
        margin: -11px 0 0 -10px;
        text-decoration: none;   
        cursor:pointer;
    }

    .root {
        list-style:none;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        font-size: 11px;
        padding: 11px 0 0 0px;
        border-top:1px solid #dedede;
    }

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link href="scripts/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/fluidcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- 
To learn more about the conditional comments around the html tags at the top of the file:
paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Do the following if you're using your customized build of modernizr (http://www.modernizr.com/):
* insert the link to your js here
* remove the link below to the html5shiv
* add the "no-js" class to the html tags at the top
* you can also remove the link to respond.min.js if you included the MQ Polyfill in your modernizr build 
-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/func1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.ajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.verticalnav > li > a').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
            $(this).siblings().toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="gridContainer clearfix">
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="AD1.php">Active Directory</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">HelpDesk</a></li>
                        <li><a href="CTS.php">CTS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Exchange/Infra</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Others</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Contact US</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="profile">
            <a class="account" >Account</a>
            <div class="submenu">
                <ul class="root">
                    <li ><a href="#Dashboard" >Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="#Profile" >Profile</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="logout.php">LogOut</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dreamweaver spelling itself is wrong! LoL. You and your Dreamviewer!!! LoL.

Comment: Hi Praveen, Sorry for the spelling mistake.

Comment: Could you help me out

Comment: Question looks crazy @BasatiNaveen. So let others answer.

Comment: I think no body to answer my question

Answer (score 0):

**Do these following changes:**

Replace the `bind` function.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $("body").bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

You have given:

```
var X = $(this).attr('id');
if (X == 1) {
```

But there's no single element or element with `.account` has an `ID` and none has an `ID` with `1`.

These event handlers do not make any sense:

```
$(".submenu").mouseup(function() {
    return false;
});

$(".account").mouseup(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Why have you given them?

And finally, this is not gonna work:

```
$(document).mouseup(function(){
    $(".submenu").hide();
    $(".account").attr('id', '');
});
```

The whole JavaScript screws up the whole page's working. So you need to extensively correct them before you do anything!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I will correct them and get back to you with the feedback.......................